# Django - Date problem in CRUD application

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, flatpickr

I'm using `flatpickr` for date informations in my Django application. The problem is when I want to update `worker` informations, in `edit.html` page default value of `birth_date` is not displaying correctly. For example, I've created worker `Xen` who was born in 01-05-1997, and click to update his name, in `birth_date` input it displays today's date. Here are my codes:

`forms.py`

```
class WorkerForm(ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = Worker  
        fields = "__all__"  
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': DateTimeInput(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', attrs={'class':'datetimefield'})
        }
```

`models.py`:

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    ...
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

`edit.html`:

```
...
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">İşçinin doğum tarixi</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input class="datetimefield" type="date" name="birth_date" id="birth_date" value="{{ worker.birth_date }}" />
  </div>
</div>
...
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            flatpickr(".datetimefield", {
                enableTime: true,
                enableSeconds: true,
                dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:S",
                time_24hr: true,
                locale: "az",
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Your dateFormat is in "php date" syntax, but flatpickr uses it's [own format string](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#supplying-dates-for-flatpickr), loosely based on `strftime()` without the `%`. Since both Python and flatpickr support ISO date strings, I highly suggest taking the simple road.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed last line of script according to @Melvyn answer:

`` defaultDate: `worker.birth_date.strftime()` ``